# Is it possible to trigger a solr replication by only changing the elevate or synonyms file?

Tags: solr

After configuring the solr.ReplicationHandler, it seams that it's only possible to trigger a replication after startup, commit or optimize.

Is it possible to configure Solr to trigger a replicate after that only the synonyms or elevate file has been updated without restarting solr, reloading the core, sending a commit or optimize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not from Solr, However replication can be triggered by using [http api](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrReplication#HTTP_API)

> Force a fetchindex on slave from master command: `http://slave_host:port/solr/replication?command=fetchindex`

Also, remember if you are changing the synonyms file, if used at indexing, you may anyways need to reindex the data.

Comment: Thanks, so I consider the answerer to be no. Good that you pointed out the request to the slave host as an alternative solution.